# MS SQL cross join performance evaluation

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I am not a DBA and am new to MS SQL...

I would like to know if an sql statement is performing poorly or not, more specifically, I would like to know whether a cross join select is performing poorly or not. Not in comparison to another select statement which may be more efficient if it is a reformulation of the original, but in comparison to itself (I understand this is a bit vague...).

For example I have the following table:

[image: table columns]

where my table has > 100K entries.

I run the following select:

```
select * from dbo.pcopy as p1, dbo.pcopy as p2;
```

It takes upwards of a day to complete. This, perhaps, is fine, but how can I ascertain this???

I have been shown the following select but cannot understand how to derive *poor perforamce* metrics from it:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_Stats
```

Comment: Well, you are selecting all of the columns twice for over 10 billion rows, how can you expect "good" performance?

Comment: What exactly do you want the query to do?  Do you really need a cartesian result of all of your data?

Comment: I am not expecting "good" performance. I am not expecting anything for that matter. I would just like to be able to get some "meaningful" metrics about the query. I chose it because it seemed as if it should be adversely affecting the DB.

Comment: f your table has over 100k entries, then the result from the query has over 100,000*100,000 = 10,000,000,000 rows. Ten billion rows is a lot of rows. If each row has 100 bytes, then you are talking about storing terabytes of results.

I cannot think of a reasonable problem where a cross join on such a large table would be needed. You should review why you are doing this and come up with a better query.

Comment: What are you trying to measure? I'd imagine this will largely be capped by whatever speed your application consumes the results.

Comment: I am trying to measure whether a query (in this respect the cross join) is over-exhausting the DB; is it running slower than it "should"; vague concepts such as these... I wish to get this data to a monitoring program.

Comment: An expensive (but simple) query like yours is probably running as it "should". But you should monitor real queries that will be executed, and not just a scenario that's hardly ever gonna come up in real life

Comment: Well you can look at the wait stats for that query. I'd imagine it will likely be `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` that is the bottle neck. If you were to take that out of the equation you could then look at the next bottle neck and so on. I don't really see the point of doing this for such an unrealistic example though.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, the point of using an unrealistic example was twofold. One, to perform some lengthy operation concerning a big amount of data and so see metrics, perhaps, blown out of proportion. Two to emulate a real situation where a Cartesian Product is encountered on two large and distinct table.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could say that a query is performing poorly by comparing the number of page read by the query, and the number of lines returned. For example, if your read thousands of pages to return one row, the query is performing poorly. In your example, you have no `WHERE` clause, so there is not a lot of room for improvement. You are doing a cartesian product with no criterion, so nothing much can be done here. You want all data, multiple times, so you get it.

If you want to improve a "real" query, a first step is to look at the reads they need to perform on each table. Less reads, better is the query. To do that, turn on IO statistics :

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

before running your query. You will have read statistics (in pages) per table in the messages pane of Management Studio.
You can also use the dynamic management view you mentioned. Compare the reads with the rows returned (the rows returned are added to this view since SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1)

```
SELECT 
    t.text, 
    execution_count, 
    total_logical_reads, 
    last_logical_reads, 
    min_logical_reads, 
    max_logical_reads,
    total_rows, 
    last_rows, 
    min_rows, 
    max_rows
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_Stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) t
```